# What is the Python syntax for importing the entire contents of a file?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to import all the classes from one Python file to the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class you wish to import from, include a variable called `__all__`, and fill it with the names of the classes/variables you want.

```
__all__ = ['Class1', 'Class2', 'variable_i_want']
```

In the class you wish to import them to, you may use the asterisk to gain access to all of the classes.

```
from foo import *
```

As suggested, be careful of name collisions when doing this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `__all__`. If you're going to use a `*` import *always* combine it with `__all__`. Otherwise, you'll seriously pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Just import the file like any other

```
import mythings
```

Then you can use

```
myClass = mythings.MyClass()
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the file "mythings.py" must exist somewhere in `sys.path` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other people are saying, the file you are importing must exist somewhere in `sys.path`.  (usually your current directory is in there, so same directory imports are no problem) For example, if you want to import from your parent directory:

```
#want to import ../myotherfile.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir))
import myotherfile  

print(myotherfile.func())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from module import *
```

You must be careful when doing this as you can get name collisions.